# PHP: How to check PHP version?

Tags: php

Is there a chance to check PHP version during execution without system calls as `exec()` or `system()`?

I think about sth like

```
$phpVersion = ... ;
if (!($phpVersion >= "7.")) {
    throw new \Error("Sorry, PHP >=7 required");
}
```

I could not find any [predefined PHP constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/com.constants.php).

Comment: I just searched and this is literally the first result: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this native function: [phpversion()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php). In my case it returns ...

```
php > echo phpversion();
7.4.3
```

If you just need to check if php version is 7 or higher ...

```
if ((int) phpversion() < 7) {
    throw new \Error("Sorry, PHP >=7 required");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`phpversion()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) to get the version in your code.

```
<?php
  echo phpversion();
```